# Jenkinsfile not finding MSBuild despite plugin registration

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-plugins

This is a simplified version of Jenkinsfile that I work on;

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    tools {
        msbuild 'MSBuild 17'
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                pwsh ('''
                    nuget restore "${env:workspace}/Sandbox.sln"
                    msbuild "${env:workspace}/Sandbox.sln" /clp:ErrorsOnly -t:build -verbosity:diag -property:Configuration=Release -property:RestorePackages=true
                ''')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have defined multiple versions of MSBuild in "Global Configuration Tool". I keep receiving  `not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

I tried `withEnv('MSBuild 17') { ... }` which didn't work either.

Does anyone have a hint how to fix this?

Comment: MsBuild Plugin don't add msbuild.exe to PATH instead of maven, jdk and gradle (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#tools). So you need give the full path of msbuild.exe to run and use `bat`, `powershell`, or `pwsh` for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use the MSBuild tool:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def msbuild_tool = tool name: 'MSBuildTools16', type: 'hudson.plugins.msbuild.MsBuildInstallation'
                    pwsh label: 'Compilation', script: '& "' + msbuild_tool + '" project.sln'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in my case, MSBuildTools16 => "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MsBuild.exe"

Another solution:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                bat "\"${tool 'MSBuildTools16'}\" project.sln"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have defined multiple versions of MSBuild in "Global Configuration Tool".

That supposed having installed the [Jenkins MSBuild plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/msbuild/), with only the parent `Bin` folder path specified in it:

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkins-infra/plugins-wiki-docs/master/msbuild/docs/images/jenkins-msbuild.png]

See [issue 56389](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-56389) for illustration:

```yaml
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
                bat "\"${tool 'MSBuild'}\\msbuild.exe\" ${SQLPROJ} /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=\"Any CPU\" /p:ProductVersion=1.0.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
            }
        }
```

Comment: So this means that "Directive Generator" code is not actually usable (pipeline syntax -> Declarative Directive Generator) ? This is where I've got the tools section.

Comment: @Bakudan Not sure indeed. Did you test it, does it work?

Comment: I had similar thing to do with another tool. This is the way to do it, and the screenshot is absolutely correct. One small change - `def msbuild_tool = tool name: 'MSBuildTools16', type: 'hudson.plugins.msbuild.MsBuildInstallation'` this seems to be the most accurate way to define as per [Damin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72395818/179669)